# ruby keywords argument destructuring

Tags: ruby, language-lawyer, destructuring, keyword-argument

I have the simple function

```
def fn(x,a:nil)
  "#{x.inspect} - #{a.inspect}"
end
```

and doing `puts fn({ 'v' => 1, :a => 2})` I get `{"v"=>1, :a=>2} - nil` as expected.

But if I make `x` optional, as in `def fn(x=nil,a:nil)`, I unexpectedly get `{"v"=>1} - 2`, i.e. the `a` part has been removed from the hash and put into the keyword argument.

Why does that only happen when `x` is optional?

(I know that the invocation is equivalent to `fn('v' => 1, :a => 2)`, and using this indeed does not change the behaviour.)

debian `ruby 2.1.5p273`, same with RHEL `ruby 2.0.0p598`.

Comment: This is a bit of a fuzzy spot, I'm not sure what [Ruby Spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec) has to say but it'd know for sure. I think `x` is just being really aggressive here and grabbing whatever it can first. In the second case `x` gets the left-overs.

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14183 or its related issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ruby doesn't distinguish between `fn({a: 2})` and `fn(**{a: 2})` so there's a lot of ambiguity when a method takes both, positional and keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby implicitly converts a hash to keyword args, here is a good post: https://makandracards.com/makandra/36013-heads-up-ruby-implicitly-converts-a-hash-to-keyword-arguments

Because of this, they recommend you do not mix keyword and optional arguments: https://makandracards.com/makandra/36011-ruby-do-not-mix-optional-and-keyword-arguments